# Does shortbread ship well?

Tags: baking, storage-lifetime, cookies

I'm planning on shipping shortbread to another state, and it may take 3-5 days to arrive to the destination. It's a fairly butter-rich cookie: 3 sticks butter, 5 cups flour, 2 cups sugar (about) plus spices. How well would they ship, and how long will they stay after shipping? Could they go rancid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortbread ships well, especially if you make the individual biscuits fairly thick.  Walker's should be your guide here: theirs are about 0.75 to 1cm thick, which helps prevent crumbling in transit.  Shipping them in a tin is also advised.

Shortbread is also fairly shelf-stable.  Freshness time depends on storage conditions, of course, but below 75F they should be good for one to two weeks.